# Populate Excel userform listbox with query data - listbox is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, listbox

I'm attempting to populate a listbox on a userform in an excel document from a query to SQL server, but the listbox is always blank.

I'm trying to get a list of locations to populate which I will use to define parameters for a follow on query.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Populate_ListBox_From_SQL()
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stDB As String, stConn As String, stSQL As String
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim k As Long

    'set SQL connection and connection string
    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    stConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DW;Data Source=use-rptdw-00;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;" _
    & "Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=PI-L-C03RTRD;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

    cnt.ConnectionString = stConn

    'your SQL statement
    stSQL = "SELECT ldesc FROM fin.location ORDER BY ldesc"

    With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Necesary for creating disconnected recordset.
        .Open stConn 'Open connection.
        'Instantiate the Recordsetobject and execute the SQL-state.
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With

    With rst
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset.
        k = .Fields.Count
         'Populate the array with the whole recordset.
        vaData = .GetRows
    End With

     'Close the connection.
    cnt.Close

     'Manipulate the Listbox's properties and show the form.
     With UserForm1
        With .ComboBox1
            .Clear
            .BoundColumn = k
            .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
            .ListIndex = -1
        End With
        .Show vbModeless
    End With

    'Release objects from memory.
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Maybe I'm putting the code in the wrong place?  I have it under the base VBA code for the userform.
Or maybe I need to set properties for the ListBox itself?

I'm pretty new to VBA so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I figured it out.  I just wasn't making an explicit call to the function.   Although, now I get "run-time error '400':  form already displayed; can't show modally" error.

Any idea how to stop that from happening?